# How to call suspend function in Activity?

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I am working on a project and I want to fetch the data from Api and display it in UI. I am using Jetpack Compose by the way. How can I call the suspend function in Main Activity? I want to fetch the list and then call the function `bookListScreen(bookList : BookList)` in `LotrAppTheme{}`. How can I do this?

Main Activity:

```
package com.example.lotrapp
 
    @AndroidEntryPoint
    class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    
        private val bookViewModel: BookViewModel by viewModels()
        private lateinit var bookList : BookList
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
            setContent {
                LOTRAppTheme {
    
                }
            }
    
        }
    }
    
    @Preview(showBackground = true)
    @Composable
    fun DefaultPreview() {
        LOTRAppTheme {
    
        }
    }
```

View Model:

```
package com.example.lotrapp

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.example.lotrapp.models.BookList
import com.example.lotrapp.repository.BookRepository
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class BookViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: BookRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    suspend fun getBookList() : BookList? {
        return repository.getBookList()
    }
}
```

BookListScreen

```
@Composable
fun bookListScreen(bookList : BookList) {

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Gray)
    ) {

        LazyColumn(
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(all = 12.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(12.dp)
        ) {
            itemsIndexed(
                items = bookList.docs
            ) {
                index, book -> BookItem(book)
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: It's a bad practice to perform business logic in `Activity`. You can call a method in the View Model which in turn calls the suspend function

Comment: Hi. You first accepted my answer, but then reversed your decision. Do you have a problem getting it to work?

Comment: Actually yeah, when I did what you said, the list was empty. idk what is the problem but don't we need to add a "by remember" somewhere in there? And it's an asynchronous function, how do we make sure it's finished before the composable function (bookListScreen) runs?

Answer (score 3):

As @gtxtreme said business logic must not be in an activity but if you're doing something in activity that requires you to launch a coroutine in a composable then you can make a coroutine scope with:

```
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
```

Then whenever you'd like to use your suspend funtion:

```
coroutineScope.launch {
  //do some suspend work
  }
```

Or if you'd like to have a coroutine scope to run your api often depending on a specific key (such as search query in local database) then use the so-called *Handlers* in compose for example:

```
LaunchedEffect(key1 = searchQuery){
            //do api call
  }
```

the code between the closures will run at the very first composition and whenever the code changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can get book list as soon as your view model is created using `init`, and store the result value in a mutable state holder: by using mutable state you're making sure your view will update when new value comes.

Check out more about state in compose [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state), including [this youtube video](https://youtu.be/mymWGMy9pYI) which explains the basic principles.

```
@HiltViewModel
class BookViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: BookRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    var bookList by mutableStateOf<BookList?>(null)

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            bookList = getBookList()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun getBookList() : BookList? {
        return repository.getBookList()
    }
}
```

Then you can display needed view depending on the state:

```
val bookList = viewModel.bookList
if (bookList != null) {
    BookListScreen(bookList)
} else {
    // loading
}
```